# Access PHP website on virtual linux machine from host machine

Tags: php, linux, apache, virtual-machine

I have installed Ubuntu Server 10 on a virtual machine (VMWare) and I have set up a LAMP stack. Everything runs fine when I go to "mysitename" in Firefox on the linux virtual machine, but when I try to access it on my windows machine, it only gives me the HTML in my .php file, and does not execute the PHP. Can anyone provide some suggestions? I'm guessing it will be an apache setting, but I'm not sure.

Comment: What are you expecting to see other than your html?

Comment: @martswite I'm expecting the HTML that is generated by the PHP instead of just the HTML that is in the file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What URL are you accessing from your Windows machine? Are you sure that the PHP file is actually interpreted when you're accessing it from the Linux Guest?

Comment: welcome to SO. As this is not an answer it would probably be more suited as a comment. :-)

Comment: @martswite, welcome to SO. Privilege 'comment everywhere' requires 50 reputation.

Comment: Turns out that the PHP does not get executed if you try to access it using the IP address, but it does if you access it using "mysitename" it does. Welcome to SO and thanks for your help.

Comment: @Brett It looks like your vhost config is wrong. Is it possible that you've added the the *.php types only to the named host?